# F# Discriminated Union - "downcasting" to subtype

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I don't really know what the proper title for this question should be, but:

I have a discriminated union called `MyDiscriminatedUnion` in `F#`:

```
type MyDiscriminatedUnion =
| Foo of Foo
| Bar of Bar
```

where `Foo` and `Bar` are record types:

```
type Foo = {
   ... }
type Bar = {
   ... }
```

I created a value of union type `Foo`:

```
let foo = Foo {
   ... }
```

The compiler tells me that foo is of type `MyDiscriminatedUnion`.

Then I want to pass foo into a function that expects type Foo, not `MyDiscriminatedUnion`. Therefore the compiler complains. How do I tell the compiler that `foo` is of type `Foo`?

I have tried:

```
let foo:Foo
```

when constructing the value of union type.

I have tried to "downcast" foo to Foo by:

```
foo :?> MyDiscriminatedUnion.Foo
```

but neither of them work.

Please help.

Comment: What happens when the members of the union have distinct names from the types? (Ie. either rename type `Foo` or the `Foo` property of `MyDiscriminatedUnion`.)

Comment: if you want `foo` to be of type `Foo` you just have to remove the `Foo` data-constructor (yeah you choose the same name): `let foo = { ... }` ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a common mistake when coming from an OO language: there are no subtypes involved in this code. The fact that you named your union cases the same as the type of the field they contain can make this confusing though, so let me give a slightly different example:

```
type MyDiscriminatedUnion =
  | Its_a_Foo of Foo
  | Its_a_Bar of Bar
```

`Its_a_Foo` and `Its_a_Bar` are *not* subtypes, they're union cases. A value of type `MyDiscriminatedUnion` is either an `Its_a_Foo`, in which case it has a field of type `Foo`, or an `Its_a_Bar`, in which case it has a field of type `Bar`. To know which one it is and get the corresponding field, you need to use pattern matching.

```
// The function that takes a record of type Foo as argument
let f (x: Foo) = ...

// Our value of type MyDiscriminatedUnion
let myDU = Its_a_Foo { ... }

// Extracting the Foo and passing it to f
match myDU with
| Its_a_Foo foo -> f foo
| Its_a_Bar bar -> // What should we do if it's an Its_a_Bar instead?

// If you're _really_ certain that myDU is Its_a_Foo { ... }, not Its_a_Bar { ... }, you can do this.
// You will get a compile-time warning "FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression".
// If it's Its_a_Bar, you will get a runtime error.
let (Its_a_Foo foo) = myDU
f foo
```

Comment: "*If it's Its_a_Bar, you will get an error.*" A _runtime_ error, not a compiler error, it's worth pointing out.

Comment: You may also get the compiler warning `FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression.`

Answer (score 1):

[Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) case here...

I needed to write a function:

```
let MapToSubtype subtype =
   match subtype with
   | Foo foo -> foo
```

Then apply the function:

```
let x = MapToSubtype foo
```

... and worked like a charm.

**Edit:** Please note that as [JustSomeFSharpGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4927972/justsomefsharpguy) pointed out the `MapToSubtype` function doesn't cover all cases so the compiler will give a warning and could give a runtime exception if something else than `Foo` is passed in.

So the function should really look like this:

```
let MapToSubtype subtype =
    match subtype with
    | Foo foo -> foo
    | _ -> // deal with exception here
```

Comment: Be aware that with your function you a) get a compiler warning due to missing cases; b) get a runtime exception if you ever pass a case that's not "Foo".

Comment: Yes, I am just certain (in this case) that what I pass in will always be Foo, but yes - you are right.

Comment: In that case you might want to add a "| _ -> invalidOp ..".