# How to restrict a DU/ADT to certain case identifiers/value constructors

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, f#

How would I approach  the following situatiuon?
I have a DU (for example a Currency) and some record type.
Now for the record type fields I have the requierements that the actual values for a given instance should al be of the same case identifier (or in Haskell the same value constructor)

```
type Currency =
    | USD of decimal
    | EUR of decimal

type PositionalData = {
    grossAmount: Currency;
    pos1: Currency;
    pos2: Currency;
}
```

for example the following is valid

```
let valid = {
    grossAmount = USD 10.0m;
    pos1 = USD 7.0m;
    pos2 = USD 3.0m;
}
```

where as this example should be invalid

```
let wrong = {
    grossAmount = USD 10.0m;
    pos1 = USD 7.0m;
    pos2 = EUR 3.0m;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

I know this particular example can be solved in F# using Units of Measurement. But its easy to envision an example that is not solvable via that mechanism.
So I like to ask you to consider a more generic answer and not necessarily one that just solves the give code example.

Looking forward to your brain dumps ;-)

PS: for all the Haskeleers around - It would be interesting to see how ADT (maybe in combination wit higher kinded types) can solve that.

Comment: I imagine you can cheat if you used some C# with the F# by taking advantage of the way the DU is compiled.

Comment: @JohnPalmer ah, no cheating and C# allowed. sorry. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *"direct"* translation could be

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

data Currency = USD | EUR deriving Show

-- We use `Currency` values to create `Amount` types
--   read about types in Haskell ([Kinds][1]: *, * -> *, ...)
--   here we fix one * to be Currency
data Amount :: Currency -> * where
     -- Data constructor, take one float and return some Amount
     Amount :: Float -> Amount a

-- Extract the specific currency symbol require extra effort
instance Show (Amount a) where
    show (Amount k) = show k

-- Many amounts (same currency)
-- `a` restrict `a1` and `a1` to have the same type => the same currency
data PData a = PData { a1 :: Amount a
                     , a2 :: Amount a
                     } deriving Show

-- Helpers
usd :: Float -> Amount USD
usd = Amount

eur :: Float -> Amount EUR
eur = Amount

main = do

    print $ PData (usd 3) (usd 4)  -- OK
    print $ PData (eur 3) (eur 4)  -- OK
    print $ PData (eur 3) (usd 4)  -- KO, Couldn't match type 'USD with 'EUR
```

(1) https://wiki.haskell.org/Kind

On the other hand, @TheInnerLight remember me you can use [phantom types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type)

```
-- NOTE: this is not a "direct translation" since currencies are not
--       enumerated and is slightly different
data USD = USD
data EUR = EUR

data Amount c = Amount { amount :: Float }

instance Show (Amount c) where
    show (Amount a) = show a

data PData c = PData { c1 :: Amount c
                     , c2 :: Amount c }
                       deriving Show

usd :: Float -> Amount USD
usd = Amount

eur :: Float -> Amount EUR
eur = Amount

main = do

    print $ PData (usd 3) (usd 4)  -- OK
    print $ PData (eur 3) (eur 4)  -- OK
    print $ PData (eur 3) (usd 4)  -- KO, Couldn't match type 'USD with 'EUR
```

One way to extract currency symbols (or any other data) could be

```
class    Symbol c   where symbol :: c -> String
instance Symbol USD where symbol _ = "USD"
instance Symbol EUR where symbol _ = "EUR"

instance Symbol c => Show (Amount c) where
    show s@(Amount a) = sym undefined s ++ " " ++ show a
                        where sym :: Symbol c => c -> Amount c -> String
                              sym k _ = symbol k
```

printing

```
PData {c1 = USD 3.0, c2 = USD 4.0}
PData {c1 = EUR 3.0, c2 = EUR 4.0}
```

Comment: thanks @josejuan. could you explain what the code starting at line 6 does (the type constructor for Amount) or give me a direction where to read it.

Comment: Note that the first `data Amount` is not really a GADT, but only a phantom type too like the second one. No GADTs have been used here, only their syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly compare subtypes of DUs in F# (also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30841893/3929902 ), but you could use this roundabout way of achieving it:

```
type USD =
    Amount of decimal
type EUR =
    Amount of decimal

type Currency = 
    | USD of USD
    | EUR of EUR

type PositionalData<'T> =
  {
      grossAmount: 'T
      pos1: 'T
      pos2: 'T
  }        

let valid = {
    grossAmount = USD.Amount 10.0m;
    pos1 = USD.Amount 7.0m;
    pos2 = USD.Amount 3.0m;
}

let wrong = {
    grossAmount = USD.Amount 10.0m;
    pos1 = USD.Amount 7.0m;
    pos2 = EUR.Amount 3.0m;
}
```

An obvious problem with this answer though is that PositionalData is not constrained to Currency, but can be of any type

Comment: thanks @klasske.  
actually your solution is pretty close to using Units of Measurement in F#. And probably if you go that route one should simply use Measurements me thinks as you can easily constrain the parameter to only measurement types.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to constrain to a particular union case because they aren't, themselves, types.  That means that the union case a particular value belongs to isn't available at compile time.

For this particular case, as you point out in your question, I would use units of measure rather the discriminated unions to solve the problem in F#.

To solve the problem more generally, it's generally better to invert the relationship to something like this:

```
type PositionalData = {
    grossAmount: decimal;
    pos1: decimal;
    pos2: decimal;
}

type Currency =
    | USD of PositionalData
    | EUR of PositionalData
```

You could make this applicable beyond `PositionalData` with a type like:

```
type Currency<'a> =
    | USD of 'a
    | EUR of 'a
```

For the Haskell case, I recommend reviewing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279100/in-haskell-how-do-you-restrict-functions-to-only-one-constructor-of-a-data-type).